# neo4j 3.0.4: Absolute path names for db file location

Tags: neo4j

In version 2.3.x I used to have multiple embedded neo4j instances on which I occasionally did some ad hoc queries from the web browser after the "main application" was shut down.
The `neo4j-community-2.3.2/conf/neo4j-server.properties` file did point to the absolute path of the database to look at (`org.neo4j.server.database.location=/tmp/neo4jbcd`), and I did start a db server by `bin/neo4j start` then.

What would be the proper equivalent in version 3.0.4?

- Simply setting the absolute path `dbms.active_database=/tmp/neo4jbcd` in `neo4j-community-3.0.4/conf/neo4j.conf` does not access an existing databse below `/tmp/neo4jbcd`, but goes to `neo4j-community-3.0.4/data/databases/tmp/neo4jbcd` as shown in the [Neo4j Operations Manual V3.0](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/deployment/#file-locations).
- Setting `dbms.directories.data=/tmp/neo4jbcd` did also not seem to have any effect.
- Chapter 2.2.2 ("Configuration") of the Operations Manual suggests to set several environment variables (`NEO4J_BIN`, `NEO4J_CONF` and `NEO4J_HOME`), but then I end up with `Error: Could not find or load main class org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint`, also if `NEO4J_BIN` is in the `PATH`.

Of course, I can go into `neo4j-community-3.0.4/data/databases/tmp`, set a symbolic link `neo4jbcd` to the real location and start a server with `dbms.active_database=/tmp/neo4jbcd` in place.

Is this the suggested best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the symlink is the easiest way to go.